# Настройка CA-сертификатов

Tags: php, symfony2

Установил Apache, PHP 5.5, Symfony2 на openSUSE 42.1 Leap. При вызове `symfony new project_name` получаю ошибку:

> No system CA bundle could be found in any of the the common system locations.
>   PHP versions earlier than 5.6 are not properly configured to use the system's
>   CA bundle by default. In order to verify peer certificates, you will need to
>   supply the path on disk to a certificate bundle to the 'verify' request
>   option: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/clients.html#verify. If you do not need a specific certificate bundle, then Mozilla provides a commonly used CA bundle which can be downloaded here (provided by the maintainer of cURL): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt. Once   you have a CA bundle available on disk, you can set the 'openssl.cafile' PHP ini setting to point to the path to the file, allowing you to omit the 'verify' request option. See http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html for more information.

Собственно что делать дальше?
В системе есть cacert.pem по пути */usr/share/pki/trust/anchors/* , его следует указать в *php.ini* как значение параметра *curl.cainfo* или следует скачать другой .pem-файл?

Сам *php.ini* тоже существует по нескольким путям: */etc/php5/cli/php.ini*, */etc/php5/apache2/* — какой из них следует использовать?

Comment: Вы вообще читаете, что Вам симфони пишет или не глядя копипастите на форумы?

Comment: Sergey, вначале я пытаюсь сделать сам, если не удалось, то гуглю, если не помогло, то спрашиваю.